# Extract dates from the titles of files in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a group of files in a folder. The names are formatted like this; credit_MM-DD-YYYY where MM-DD-YYYY is a date. MM is a month number (01 to 12), DD is the day of the month (01 to 31) and YYYY is the year, e.g. 2019. For each file I need to extract the date, reformat the date and pass the formatted date as a parameter to another batch file which will filter the data in the file that I extracted the original date from. My problem is that I do not know how to get the date out of the file title and into a variable that I can parse. I have the filtering batch file working so that's not an issue. I don't want to use a third party utility even if it's free. I appreciate any help. If what I want to do is impossible just let me know. Thanks for your time.

I can do everything I need to do if I can just get the date from the file name into a variable.  I have spent a couple of days looking through this site and others but cannot find an answer. Below is what the short version of I have tried. 
PS I'm not a batch file pro

```
  set local
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  for %%i IN (c:\MyFolder\*credit_*.*) DO (
     echo i=%%i
     set b_name=%%i
     echo b %b_name%
  )
 echo done
 endlocal

What I get is:

  echo i=c:\MyFolder\credit_02-14-2019.txt
  set b_name=c:\MyFolder\credit_02-14-2019.txt
  echo b

  ...and on and on and on until the last file in the folder is shown...

  echo done
```

Comment: I don't think you need to explain what a date is. There **are** similar questions here on [SO] what about searching first possible keywords: parse date from file name. [SO] is not a script writing service, own research and coding attempts are expected. When you get stuck come back and present your code in a [mcve]. BTW you should also read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You've omitted the most important piece of information, what exactly is the intended date format? If you can separate the basename from the extension, you should be able to reorder and/or remove the last 10 characters of each basename. Anything more complex than that, I'd suggest you use PowerShell, which is installable from Windows XP and built-in to all systems from Windows 7.

Comment: Your text implies only the date changes in the name, but your code implies that you may have other characters before "credit_". Which is it? There is a trivial batch solution for the first situation, whereas the 2nd is more complicated.

Comment: Thanks to all for taking the time to comment. This is my first question on SO and I apologize for the poor technique used in formulating the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few techniques to manipulate a variable. You could in theory use a `FOR /F` command to split up the file name using the underscore and hyphen as delimiters.  But since the date is the last 10 positions of the file name you can use the substring feature of the `SET` command.  I have commented the code where I felt it needed explanation.

```
@echo off

REM Get a list of files in the folder.
for %%G IN (c:\MyFolder\*credit_*.*) DO (
    REM Set a variable to the base file name
    set "base=%%~nG"
    REM We are inside a parentheses code block. Must use delayed expansion.
    REM All environmental variables must be reference with exclamation points
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    REM Last 10 bytes are the date in the base file name
    REM Using negative substring expansion
    set "yyyy=!base:~-4,4!"
    set "mm=!base:~-10,2!"
    set "dd=!base:~-7,2!"
    echo File Path:%%~fG
    echo File Name:%%~nxG
    echo File Year:!yyyy!
    echo File Month:!mm!
    echo File Day:!dd!
    endlocal
)
```